# Regex validation which should have atleast one special character except special characters (? and _)

Tags: regex

I need a Regular expression validation which should have atleast any one special character except  special characters (`?` and `_`).

Valid:

1. `abcd%&`
2. `$ghksj`

Invalid:

1. `hhsh?`
2. `nxx_hus`

I have tried this

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()+=[\]{}|\\,.: -]*$)
```

Comment: Maybe ``^[a-zA-Z0-9`!@#$%^&*()+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/~]*$``? 
See https://regex101.com/r/YXtbi8/1

Comment: Why aren't `_` and `?` supposed to be accepted? I assume this is for a password?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9`!@#$%^&*()+=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/~-]*$).*
```

[**Regex proof**](https://regex101.com/r/OAtyOb/2)

If lookaround not required:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9`!@#$%^&*()+=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/~-]*$
```

[Regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/OAtyOb/3).